# Jenkins Test Result History

Tags: jenkins, mstest

At the moment we have our Jenkins Jobs configured so the Test Results get written to a specific file and then published. The problem with this is the next time the build runs it replaces the previous test results. This means the link the the email notification points to the same test results file and we are not able to debug why the tests failed.

Is there a way to create test results with a unique name like a time stamp and publish these?

Comment: What programming language and test framework are you using ?

Comment: using MSTest and C# .net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the archive function of Jenkins. Add the post build action "Archive artifacts" to your job and give the filename pattern of your test file. Now the file is archived for every job. The link in the mail notification may still point to the newest file, but you can download the archived files in the web interface of Jenkins (if you go to a specific build, you see all archived artifacts of that build).